# Set CSS for dynamic element CoffeeScript

Tags: css, coffeescript

I am trying to write a code that set CSS for some dynamic elements added on click on a link.

As per the example code in CoffeeScript tutorial it should be working with the following code.

```
temp = temp+1
$ '.box_'+temp
.css 'background', 'white'
```

Here `temp` is a variable integer.
I tried with static values like

```
$ '.box_1'
.css 'background', 'white'
```

but it returns something like this with .css not a function error

```
$('.box_1'.css('left', 100));
```

Comment: Strange. My compiler compiles your examples to `$('.box_' + temp).css('background', 'white');` and `$('.box_1').css('background', 'white');`. (version 1.8.0)

Comment: What's wrong with throwing in some parentheses to clarify your intent? `$(".box_#{temp}").css('background', 'white')` or `$(".box_#{temp}").css 'background', 'white'` are perfectly good CoffeeScript. Code is supposed to be readable, if you have to spend more than a second parsing the syntax then the code is effectively broken.

Comment: its not working even with static value `.box_1`

Comment: The [official CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24%20'.box_1'%0A.css%20'background'%2C%20'white') disagrees with you. The only way I've been able to get your results is to put it all on one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add parens to remove ambiguity and save yourself the headache.

```
temp = temp+1
$('.box_'+temp)
.css('background', 'white')
```

Sexy function calls are *optional* syntactic sugar, not required. You should not be using language features if doing so makes your code less clear for humans or machines (or in this case, both!)